# r - create multipolygon from overlapping polygons using sf package

Tags: r, polygon, data-frame, sf

I'm trying to remove overlapping areas from multiple polygons using `sf` like the following:

```
# sample polygon
poly <- data.frame(
    lon = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0.8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
    lat = c(0, 0, 1, 1.5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    var = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3, 4 ,4 ,4, 4, 4)
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
group_by(var) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = F) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")
```

In my data there are several hundred polygons and many of them are overlapping multiple times. So it would be great if there is a way to remove overlapping areas from a `sf dataframe` like in the example. I tried something with `st_difference` but I thought there might be a better way than applying this to each pair of polygons which would result in too many permutations.

[image]

Comment: can you try: mp <- poly %>% mutate(var = 1) %>% group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") . Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: sebdalgarno thank you for your answer but I realized that what I want to do may be easier if I stick to polygons and not convert to multipolygon. I updated the question now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the intersection of polygons and then filter those that overlap.

```
inter <- st_intersection(poly) %>% filter(n.overlaps < 2)
plot(inter %>% select(var)
```

[image]

Comment: hi, have a look at this similar *bounty* question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078151/ggplot2-how-to-fill-nested-polygons-with-colour . Maybe you can help..thanks