# st_intersection failing for overlapping multipolygons in sf

Tags: r, sf

I'm working with some user classification data on a citizen science platform. The way our workflow works is to take multiple user classifications of areas, overlay them on one another, and then look for consensus choice - see https://blog.floatingforests.org/2018/01/05/kelpy-consensus/ for context.

We're transitioning our codebase over to work with `sf` instead of `sp` in R for multiple reasons (one being that we've re-written the platform, so we have to re-write the pipeline anyway). As part of that rewrite, we're looking to just stay within the `sf` ecosystem in order to do out consensus operations instead of going back and forth to rasters (which we could using `fasterize`, but going from raster to polygon is a PITA). Inspired by [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280671/r-create-multipolygon-from-overlapping-polygons-using-sf-package) on gis.stackexchange, I've been trying to use `st_intersection`, but getting odd results. Here's a reprex.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3

#load the data
test_set <- devtools::source_gist("c95701bd444cda3e342838fd9a090fb3",
 filename = "test_set.R")$value

#visualize
plot(test_set)
```

[image]

So far so good, but when I try and get the intersection...

```
#get the intersection
overlap <- st_intersection(test_set)
```

I get the following error:

```
#> Error in CPL_nary_intersection(x): Evaluation error:
  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or
  near point 314406.13208707399 -5762352.8343122564 at 
  314406.13208707399 -5762352.8343122564.
```

This led me to find the "0 buffer" trick [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/347), but...

```
#What about if we add a buffer?
test_set_buff <- test_set %>%
  mutate(geometry = map(geometry, ~st_buffer(.x, 0)))

overlap_buff <- st_intersection(test_set_buff)
```

which throws the following error (even if I up the buffer a bit)

```
Error in CPL_nary_intersection(x) : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection
 between LINESTRING (312816 -5.76168e+06, 312816 -5.76168e+06) and
  LINESTRING (312816 -5.76168e+06, 312816 -5.76168e+06) at 
  312815.57772721699 -5761684.4256249201.
```

I worried this might be due to invalid polygons, so, I did some digging and pulled up the lovely `lwgeom`

Sure enough, only two of the multipolygons were above. So, I attempted `st_make_valid` - which successfully made them all valid - but...

```
#Test set valid with lwgeom
test_set_valid <- lwgeom::st_make_valid(test_set) %>% st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")

overlap_valid <- st_intersection(test_set_valid)
```

Which produces the same non-noded error. I fear that it *might* be due to some users making selections like

[image]

which have some overlap in them - but I'm unsure. It could be something else. Any suggestions for fixes here?

**Update** After reading [this thorough thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50399/how-best-to-fix-a-non-noded-intersection-problem-in-postgis), tried the following to both snap to grid and then make valid. Still the non-noded intersection issue.

```
#Snap to grid at 10m, as Landsat is only a 30m resolution anyway
test_set_snap <- test_set %>%
  mutate(geometry = map(geometry, ~lwgeom::st_snap_to_grid(.x, 10)))%>%
  mutate(geometry = map(geometry, lwgeom::st_make_valid))

overlap_snap <- st_intersection(test_set_snap)
```

Comment: You don't need quite so much piping. `test_buff = st_buffer(test_set, dist=0)` will do.

Comment: Oh, cool - didn't know to what extent I needed to handle things on a row by row basis myself or not.  Not that it solves the problem...

Comment: In case it's helpful - `Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3`

Comment: I've minimised it down to a set of five POLYGON objects that give the same error on `st_intersection`. Drop any one of the five and it works.... It also works if you intersect the five objects in reverse order.... I'm stumped...

Comment: Weird - which five? gist link? That seems odd enough that it might be worth bringing up as an issue on the sf github page for @edzer-pebesma perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

This could be some error in the underlying geometry operations code. Here's a subset of your data containing five `POLYGON` objects which produces an error when intersected one way but not in the opposite order. Get the data into your current directory as `p.R` with this (warning, overwrites anything called `p.R` in your working directory):

```
download.file("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/barryrowlingson/4665509c3c00c65ccdc0cc73b4ff10dd/raw/2132f4caf3a4629569f2ccc0727b6f5c4180f743/p.R",destfile="p.R")
```

Then get `sf` and load it:

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.6.2, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
> p = dget("./p.R")
```

Intersecting fails:

```
> st_intersection(p)
Error in CPL_nary_intersection(x) : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (313357 -5.75792e+06, 313357 -5.75792e+06) and LINESTRING (313357 -5.75792e+06, 313357 -5.75792e+06) at 313357.29442873126 -5757920.173200381.
```

But in the other order it works:

```
> st_intersection(p[5:1])
Geometry set for 12 features 
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 312547.9 ymin: -5760210 xmax: 313696.4 ymax: -5757599
epsg (SRID):    32721
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=21 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
MULTIPOLYGON (((312862.8 -5760108, 312778.8 -57...
MULTIPOLYGON (((313408.8 -5758713, 313408.8 -57...
MULTIPOLYGON (((313534.7 -5758302, 313534.7 -57...
MULTIPOLYGON (((313680.5 -5757599, 313696.4 -57...
POLYGON ((313303.8 -5759322, 313282.8 -5759322,...
```

I'm pretty sure `st_intersection` operations with one parameter should be invariant to the order of the input features, which makes me think this is a bug.

Comment: FYI, filed this here - https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/936 - and it seems like there may be a bigger issue that isn't currently being handled by geos.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to abandon `st_intersect` and instead rasterize the whole thing and convert back to an `sf` object. Not ideal, slow, and loooong code, but, see an example here - https://gist.github.com/jebyrnes/77a0efd00f7f5a1f142859ac0153f271

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to break things up into polygons

```
polys <- test_set  %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

poly_intersect <- polys %>%
  lwgeom::st_make_valid() %>%
  st_intersection()
```

This at least creates a different error

```
Error in CPL_nary_intersection(x) : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: side location 
  conflict at 317418.21159758477 -5755982.6545553887.
```

*sad trombone*